# How can I solve v-model with vuex?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

My codepen like this : https://codepen.io/skineur/pen/JjjGoEo

In the codepen, there is no error. Because v-model datepicker `<v-date-picker v-model="foo.date">`, it is taken from `data`. So if I select date in the datepicker, there is no error

My problem is v-model datepicker is not taken from `data`. But it is taken from  `state` vuex store

My computed to get data like this :

```
export default {
    ...
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["foos"])
    }
}
```

My vuex store like this :

```
import api from "../../services/api";

const state = {
  foos: []
};
// getters
const getters = {
  foos: state => state.foos,
}

// actions
const actions = {
  async getFoos({ commit }, payload) {
    commit("setLoading", true);
    let result = await api.getFoos(payload);
    const items = result.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let payload = {
          id: items[i].id,
        }; 
        let resultSchedule = await api.getFooSchedule(payload);

        items[i].schedule = resultSchedule.data
        items[i].date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    }

    commit("setDataFoo", { items: items });
  }
};

// mutations
const mutations = {
  setDataFoo(state, { items }) {
    state.foos = items;
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

If foos is taken from state and it executed, there exist error :

```
do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Note :

1. in the codepen, there is no error. because foos is taken from `data`
2. there is exist error if foos is taken from `state` vuex store. The error appears when selecting a date

Comment: See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah. But I need a spesific answer

Answer (score 2):

`getters` are readonly, you can only update store state via mutations Vuex can't match up getters to mutations automatically because they are user defined.

You can however specifically define the behaviour of get and set:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['foos']),
  // Define what happens when we get and set `date`
  date: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.foos.date;
    },
    set(newValue) {
      return this.$store.commit('foos/setDate', newValue);
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: `foos` is array. so it's not possible to call `foos.date`